# Quando utilizar banco de dados distribuido?

Tags: banco-de-dados

Eu gostaria de saber um exemplo em qual situação eu iria precisar de utilizar um banco de dados distribuido?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Bancos de Dados Distribuídos

O conceito `Distributed Database` basicamente consiste em manter distintas instâncias de um banco de dados funcionando em simultâneo.

---

Existem varias formas de se distribuir um banco de dados podendo estas ser:

- Multiplas localizações fisicas
- Redes locais
- Intranet/Extranets
- Distintos Provedores

---

### Quando a distribuição de banco de dados se faz necessária?

- Necessidade de garantir a disponibilidade, se um servidor cair o outro provavelmente estará disponível.
- Segurança para evitar a perda de informações.
- Melhorar a performance do banco de dados, em vez de uma única máquina ser responsável por prover os dados duas ou mais máquinas assumem esta responsabilidade

Mas infelizmente como toda solução tem seus problemas, distribuir um bando de dados exige que você adote uma das medidas abaixo:

**Replicação**, envolve o uso de um software que identifique para as mudanças na base de dados. Uma vez que as alterações tenham sido identificadas, o processo de replicação faz com que todos os bancos de dados tenham a mesma aparência. O processo de replicação pode ser complexo e demorado em função do tamanho e número de bases de dados repartidas. Esse processo também pode exigir muito tempo e recursos de computador.

**Duplicação**, por outro lado, com menos complexidade, este processo basicamente identifica um banco de dados como um mestre e em seguida, duplica esse banco de dados em outra localidade. O processo de duplicação é normalmente feito em um intervalo pré-definido para assegurar que cada local distribuído tenha os mesmos dados. No processo de duplicação, os usuários podem alterar apenas o banco de dados mestre. Isso garante que os dados estejam sempre íntegros nas demais instâncias.